# How to print a specific combination of character (\') in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I've some problem with string manipulation actually...
I would like to have a string like this for example "Hel\'lo", but, as you know, if I try to print this string for example, python will return "hel'lo" and not "hell\'lo"...

So, do you know a way to have a string of this form ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as always. Double the backslash.

```
3>> print("hel\\'lo")
hel\'lo
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a raw string (note the leading `r`):

```
>>> print(r"hel\'lo")
hel\'lo
```

See [Raw String and Byte Literals](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=raw#string-and-bytes-literals).